# Windows CMD Commands corresponding to linux commands

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd

```
wget http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-3.00.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tesseract-3.00.tar.gz
rm -f tesseract-3.00.tar.gz
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jpeg libjpeg
git checkout e0eadaa39b72e33f032220246c771d7302ebeaf8
cd ..
export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/tesseract-3.00
```

Above mentioned are some Linux commands. I need the corresponding Windows commands of the above mentioned ones. Please help.

Comment: most of those are going to be the same in windows... you just need to download + install the right bits (git for example)... others like 'cd' are part of the standard shell...

Comment: @forsvarir: Actually, only `cd` is the same; the majority are tools they need to download anyway and `rm` and `export` need adjustment.

Comment: @Joey How can we download the tools..means from where??/

Comment: Git from http://git-scm.com, `wget` and `tar` e.g. from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at least `wget`, `tar` and `git` installed anyway. As far as I know `git` comes with half of Cygwin anyway so you'd have the other commands (and a `bash`) available.

In any case:

- `wget` → `wget`
- `tar` → `tar`
- `rm -f` → `del /f`
- `git` → `git`
- `cd ..` → `cd ..`
- `export` → `set`:

  ```
  set TESSERACT_PATH=%CD%\tesseract-3.00
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use a Windows Git client, like [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/), to download [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout) sources. Or you could simple download their [latest Windows EXE release](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-3.00.1.exe.zip&can=2&q=). Probably you'd be better downloading the compiled release anyway. Building from scratch assumes some basic knowledge.